# Splitting a large ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, split, gps

I'm newish to python and even more new to pandas, numpy. I'm trying to format a GPS RINEX file so that the file is split into satellites (32 in total). Each file (i.e. satellite) should then be formatted so by epoch (30 second intervals), where each of the signals' data (7 in total) is then displayed in the correnponding columns. For example:

```
SV1
2014-11-07 00:00:00 L1    L2    P1    P2    C1    S1    S2 
2014-11-07 00:00:30 L1    L2    P1    P2    C1    S1    S2 
2014-11-07 00:00:30 L1    L2    P1    P2    C1    S1    S2
```

The code, in particular the function, which I'm working on is:

```
def read_data_chunk(self, RINEXfile, CHUNK_SIZE = 10000):
    obss = np.empty((CHUNK_SIZE, TOTAL_SATS, len(self.obs_types)), dtype=np.float64) * np.NaN
    llis = np.zeros((CHUNK_SIZE, TOTAL_SATS, len(self.obs_types)), dtype=np.uint8)
    signal_strengths = np.zeros((CHUNK_SIZE, TOTAL_SATS, len(self.obs_types)), dtype=np.uint8)
    epochs = np.zeros(CHUNK_SIZE, dtype='datetime64[us]')
    flags = np.zeros(CHUNK_SIZE, dtype=np.uint8)

    i = 0
    while True:
        hdr = self.read_epoch_header(RINEXfile)
        #print hdr
        if hdr is None:
            break
        epoch, flags[i], sats = hdr
        epochs[i] = np.datetime64(epoch)
        sat_map = np.ones(len(sats)) * -1
        for n, sat in enumerate(sats):
            if sat[0] == 'G':
                sat_map[n] = int(sat[1:]) - 1
        obss[i], llis[i], signal_strengths[i] = self.read_obs(RINEXfile, len(sats), sat_map)
        i += 1
        if i >= CHUNK_SIZE:
            break

    print "obss.ndim: {0}".format(obss.ndim)
    print "obss.shape: {0}" .format(obss.shape)
    print "obss.size: {0}".format(obss.size)
    print "obss.dtype: {0}".format(obss.dtype)
    print "obss.itemsize: {0}".format(obss.itemsize)
    print "obss: {0}".format(obss)

    y = np.split(obss, 32, 1)
    print "y.ndim: {0}".format(y[3].ndim)
    print "y.shape: {0}" .format(y[3].shape)
    print "y.size: {0}".format(y[3].size)
    print "y_0: {0}".format(y[3])

    return obss[:i], llis[:i], signal_strengths[:i], epochs[:i], flags[:i]
```

The print statements are there just to understand the dimensions involved, the results of which:

```
obss.ndim: 3
obss.shape: (10000L, 32L, 7L)
obss.size: 2240000
obss.dtype: float64
obss.itemsize: 8
y.ndim: 3
y.shape: (10000L, 1L, 7L)
y.size: 70000
```

The exact problem I'm encountering is just how to manipulate exactly so that the array is split into its subsequent 32 parts (i.e. the satellites).  Below is an example of the output so far:

```
sats = np.rollaxis(obss, 1, 0) 
sat = sats[5] #sv6 
sat.shape: (10000L, 7L) 
sat.ndim: 2 
sat.size: 70000 
sat.dtype: float64 
sat.item
size: 8 
sat: [[ -7.28308440e+06 -5.66279406e+06 2.38582902e+07 ..., 2.38582906e+07 4.70000000e+01 4.20000000e+01] [ -7.32362993e+06 -5.69438797e+06 2.38505736e+07 ..., 2.38505742e+07 4.70000000e+01 4.20000000e+01] [ -7.36367675e+06 -5.72559325e+06 2.38429526e+07 ..., 2.38429528e+07 4.60000000e+01 4.20000000e+01]
```

The output above is for the 6th satellite ("sat") and shows the signals for the first 3 epochs. I tried the below code to open up new files separately but the resulting text files just displayed the output below:

Code:

```
for i in range(32): 
    sat = obss[:, i] 
    open(((("sv{0}").format(sat)),'w').writelines(sat))
```

Output in text file:

```
ø ø ø ø ø ø ø
```

So obviously there's something wrong with the manipulation of the array that I'm overlooking. The `read_data_chunk` function is called from the `read_data` function:

```
def read_data(self, RINEXfile): 
    obs_data_chunks = [] 
    while True: 
        obss, _, _, epochs, _ = self.read_data_chunk(RINEXfile) 
        if obss.shape[0] == 0: 
            break 

        obs_data_chunks.append(pd.Panel( np.rollaxis(obss, 1, 0), items=['G%02d' % d for d in range(1, 33)], major_axis=epochs,minor_axis=self.obs_types).dropna(axis=0, how='all').dropna(axis=2, how='all'))   

    print "obs_data_chunks: {0}".format(obs_data_chunks) 
    self.data = pd.concat(obs_data_chunks, axis=1)
```

The next step I tried was in the above code, as I figured this array is perhaps the right one to be manipulated. The final print statement:

```
obs_data_chunks: [<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'> 
Dimensions: 32 (items) x 2880 (major_axis) x 7 (minor_axis) 
Items axis: G01 to G32 
Major_axis axis: 2014-04-27 00:00:00 to 2014-04-27 23:59:30 
Minor_axis axis: L1 to S2]
```

I tried to figure out how to deal with the `obs_data_chunks` array using:

```
odc = np.rollaxis(obs_data_chunks, 1) 
odc_temp = odc[5]
```

but received an error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'`

Comment: There is a [StackExchange GIS site](http://gis.stackexchange.com) - someone over there may have solved this already.  In the meantime it would help if you could show us an example of ```obss``` with a couple of *rows* for two or three satellites.

Comment: @wwii - GPS != GIS.  I'm guessing the OP is wanting to do detailed geodesy work (e.g. plate motions, etc). Either way, this isn't a GIS-related question. Regardless, you're quite right that a bit more example data would help immensely.

Comment: @JoeKington - I imagine that there are folks over there that are familiar with RINEX, geodesy, GPS, geowhatever .... and they often use Python to solve their problems.  That said, I did find an interesting [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18021056/2823755) and answer.

Comment: Looks to me like they already are "split": just index along axis 1. If you want to loop through the 32 satellites or something you can make that be the first axis as: `y = np.rollaxis(obss, 1)`, then `y.shape` is `(32, 10000, 7)` and if you do anything to `y[0]` it'll be the first satellite, or if you want to loop through each satellite, `for sat in y: ...` will give you one satellite at a time.

Comment: Looking at your updates now, @pymat. you pasted things over in a few ways (seems repetitive) but I think the last thing you have (the `pd.Panel`) is the best way to proceed. And you don't need to roll it because the satellite axis is already the first axis: try `obs_data_chunks[0]` and you'll have your first satellite.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly you want to do with these 32 satellite subsets.  As far as I can tell, the way you currently have `obss`, with shape `(10000, 32, 7)`, you already have it "split" in a way. Here's how you can access them:

1. Slice along the 'satellite' dimension, which is `axis=1`:

   ```
   sat = obss[:, 0]  # all the data for satellite 0, with shape (10000, 7)
   sat = obss[:, i]  # for any i from 0 through 31.
   sats = obss[:, :3] # the first three satellites
   ```
2. If you find that you are mainly indexing by satellite, you can move its axis to the front with [`np.rollaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html):

   ```
   sats = np.rollaxis(obss, 1)
   sats.shape
   # (32, 10000, 7)
   sat = sats[i]  # satellite i, equivalent to obss[:, i]
   sat = sats[:3] # first three satellites
   ```
3. If you want to loop through the satellites, as you would in your `y = np.split(obss)` example, an easier way to do that is:

   ```
   for i in range(32):
       sat = obss[:, i]
       ...
   ```

   or, if you roll the axis for `sats`, you can just do:

   ```
   sats = np.rollaxis(obss, 1)
   for sat in sats:
       ...
   ```
4. Finally, if you really want a list of the satellites, you can do

   ```
   sats = np.rollaxis(obss, 1)
   satlist = list(sats)
   ```

Comment: Hi @pymat, can you post that information in your question as an update? It's very hard to read and impossible to copy from the comments. If you do that I'll be happy to read it and help you along. Just comment here once more to let me know you've done it. (you can get my attention by typing `@askewchan` in your comment).

Comment: just added it. Cheers. @askewchan